# Confused about the use of ptrdiff_t in C++

Tags: java, c++, porting

I need to translate this line of code in Java and I am
not sure what to do about ptrdiff_t. Not sure what it does here. By the way, mask_block
is of type size_t.

```
size_t lowest_bit = mask_block & (-(ptrdiff_t)mask_block);
```

Thanks

Comment: lowest_bit is the least significant bit or the most significant bit?

Comment: @AdamStelmaszczyk all bits but the least significant bit are cleared

Comment: So, can't we just make `mask_block & 1`?

Comment: @AdamStelmaszczyk No, it is the least significant bit that is not zero. Thus, the result is `mask_block & (1 << pos_of_lowest_set_bit)`.

Answer (score 6):

Beware! This is bit magic!

`( x & ~(x-1) )` returns the lowest set bit in an expression. The author of the original code decided to use `( x & (-x) )` which is effectively the same due to the [two's comlement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation of integers. But (the original author thought that) to get `-x` you need to use signed types and, as pointed out earlier, `ptrdiff_t` is signed, `size_t` is unsigned.

As Java does not have unsigned types, `mask_block` will be `int` and `mask_block & (-mask_block)` will work without any issue.

Note that due to the interoperability between signed and unsigned types, the cast is superfluous in C++ as well.

Answer (score 4):

`ptrdiff_t` is the type that should be used for the (integer) difference between two pointers. That is, the result of subtracting one pointer from another. It is a signed integer, and should be large enough to stroe the size of largest possible array (so in Java, that would simply be an `int`, I'd guess)

Comment: Yes. Or rather, use the signed version of whatever you translate `size_t` as in the target program.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri `ptrdiff_t` is a fixed type that does not vary according to what kind of pointers you have. It simply depends on how large the addressing space of the computer is (in other words, usually 32 or 64 bits).

Comment: I am not sure if anything you guys said is related to my question at all :(

Comment: @user1796942 err, why not? I believe I answered the question as it stands. IF that's not what you wanted to know, you should probably clarify your question.

Comment: jalf, I am still not sure what -(ptrdiff_t)mask_block does. The best I can guess is that it changes only the most significant bit, because of the minus sign.

Comment: No, `ptrdiff_t` is a _type_, so `(ptrdiff_t)` changes the type of the expression, in this case, `mask_block`, to a ptrdiff_t. Just like in Java! And then the `-` makes the result negative.

Comment: So if we assume `ptrdiff_t` to be a 64 bit signed integer, the resulting Java would simply be `-(long)mask_block`.

Comment: Mr. Lister, but it is very confusing why they do that, why would you change the type like that, in this case specifically?

Comment: I don't know _why_ they do that, I don't have the context that line is in. I might probably write `lowest_bit = mask_block&1`.

Comment: @user1796942 because according to your post, `mask_block` is a `size_t`, which is unsigned. You can't flip the sign on an unsigned variable, so they cast it to `ptrdiff_t`, which is signed.

Comment: Anyway, if you wanted to know what the line *as a whole* does, then it is kind of misleading to ask a question in which you mention `ptrdiff_t` specifically. That leads to getting answers like mine, which tell you what the `ptrdiff_t` is for **because that is what you asked**, rather than explaining what the line as a whole does (which apparently was what you wanted to know?) In general, you're going to get much better answers if you actually ask the question that you want answered. ;)

Answer (score 4):

`ptrdiff_t` is the name of a type, like `int` or `::std::string`. The C++ standard promises that this type will be an integer type large enough to hold the difference between any two pointers that you can subtract. Of course, the idea of subtracting pointers is a rather foreign concept in Java. In order to be able to do this, `ptrdiff_t` must be able to hold negative numbers.

The sub-expression in which `ptrdiff_t` is used is a cast expression, like a Java typecast. However, unlike a Java typecast, C++ cast expressions are more dangerous and uglier. They can be used for all kinds of different type conversions that Java would balk at. And sometimes they will yield surprising results.

In this case, it looks like someone needed a value which was an unsigned integer of some kind (maybe an `unsigned long` or something) to be able to be negative. They needed to turn it into a signed value. `ptrdiff_t` is typically the largest size integer the platform supports. So if you're going to turn an arbitrary unsigned integer type into a signed one `ptrdiff_t` would be the type to use that would be least likely to result in some kind of odd truncation or sign change with C++'s rather ugly cast operation.

In particular, it looks like the type they wanted was `size_t`, which is another type in the C++ standard. It *is* an unsigned type (just like I was guessing), and is guaranteed to be an integer type that's big enough to hold the size of any possible object in memory. It's usually the same size as `ptrdiff_t`.

The reason the person who wrote the code wanted to do this was an interesting bit manipulation trick. To show you the trick, I'll show you how this expression plays out in a number of scenarios.

Suppose `mask_block` is 48. Lets say that on this hypothetical platform, `size_t` is 16 bits (which is very small, but this is just an example). In binary then, `mask_block` looks like this:

```
0000 0000 0011 0000
```

And `-(ptrdiff_t)mask_block` is -48, which looks like this:

```
1111 1111 1101 0000
```

So, `48 & -48` is this:

```
0000 0000 0001 0000
```

Which is 16. Notice that this is the value of the lowest set bit in 48.  Lets try 50. 50 looks like this:

```
0000 0000 0011 0010
```

And -50 looks like this:

```
1111 1111 1100 1110
```

So, `50 & -50` looks like this:

```
0000 0000 0000 0010
```

Which is 2. Notice again how this is the value of the lowest set bit in 50.

So this is just a trick to find the value of the lowest set bit in `mask`. The fact the variable is called `lowest_bit` should be a clue there. :-)

Of course, this trick isn't completely portable. Some platforms that C and (maybe C++ by now) run on do not use twos complement representation, and this trick won't work on those platforms.

In Java, you can just do this `long lowest_bit = mask_block & -mask_block;` and get the same effect. Java guarantees twos complement integers and doesn't even have unsigned integers. So it should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

`x & -x` is a bit hack that clears all bits of `x` excluding its lowest bit.

For all non-zero values of `x`, it is `1 << lb`, where `lb` is the position of the least significant bit (counting starting with 0).

Why is it casted to `ptrdiff_t`? Without further knowledge it is difficult to say. I'm not even sure that the cast is needed. [`ptrdiff_t`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstddef/ptrdiff_t/) is guaranteed to be a signed integral type and [`size_t`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstddef/size_t/) is always an unsigned integral type. So, I guess that the author of the C++ code wanted to be sure that it is signed and has the same size as a pointer. It should be sufficient to port the code to Java by simply ignoring the cast, as in Java all integers are signed anyway.

The resulting code will also be more portable than the original C/C++ version, which assumes that the machine uses [2's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) to represent integers, although it is (at least in theory) not guaranteed by the C or C++ standard. In Java, however, it is guaranteed that the JVM must use 2's complement.